# Install package

Tags: software-installation, software-center, source-packages

I got message like:

```
E: The package libgtksourceview2.0-0 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtksourceview2.0-0`

Comment: [That package is in universe](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgtksourceview2.0-0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/) for installing the missing/corrupted packages. Which can be installed from software center or can be installed by running the following commands in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, reinstall it with `sudo apt remove <package forgot its name>` then `sudo apt install package`.